# iterate through array and store results

Tags: ios, swift

I have an array called thoughtArray which is an array of a custom object called ThoughtObject. ThoughtObject has a property called 'createdDate' which holds an NSDate, the date that the object was created.

I need to filter through that array and find all the objects that match the current date and then append them to another array.

So far all attempts have been unsuccessful. This is what i've tried below.

```
for createdToday in thoughtArray {
        if (createdToday.createdDate?.isEqualToDate(NSDate()) != nil) {
            createdTodayArray.append(createdToday)

        }
    }
```

The problem is that even objects that have the createdToday property set to a few days ago get added to the array.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you have != nil in your if statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems. First, the "optional chaining"

```
createdToday.createdDate?.isEqualToDate(NSDate()
```

returns `nil` or not, depending on whether `createdToday.createdDate`
is `nil` or not. That is not what you want.

Second, as already stated by @thelaws in his answer, `isEqualToDate()`
returns only `yes` if the two dates represent exactly the same moment in time. `NSCalendar` has a

```
func compareDate(date1: NSDate, toDate date2: NSDate, toUnitGranularity unit: NSCalendarUnit) -> NSComparisonResult
```

method (available since iOS 8) which can be used here:

```
let cal = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let now = NSDate()
for createdToday in thoughtArray {
    if let createdAt = createdToday.createdDate {
        // compare with "day granularity":
        if cal.compareDate(createdAt, toDate: now, toUnitGranularity: .CalendarUnitDay) == .OrderedSame {
              createdTodayArray.append(createdToday)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An `NSDate` object represents a specific moment in time. Thus, it's very unlikely that a date in your array represents exactly NOW.

There are several approaches to determine if a date is today. You could turn the date into `NSDateComponents` and compare the year, month and day.

Comment: Ok thanks for helping out with that part although objects that were created a few days ago are still being added to the array. In fact, every single item in the thoughtArray is being added to the createdTodayArray.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `compareDate` function mentioned by Martin and the filter function of Array:

```
var thoughtArray = [ThoughtObject]()
var cal = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
var createdToday = thoughtArray.filter {
    if let createdDate = $0.createdDate {
        return cal.compareDate(NSDate(), toDate: createdDate, toUnitGranularity: .CalendarUnitDay) == .OrderedSame
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```